laravel-vite generate relative path instead of absolute path
how can I make vite generate relative URLs?
I already tried this:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.css'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
    base: ''
});

But all I get are still absolute URLs when including the CSS file by using:
@vite('resources/css/app.css')

Any idea what I do wrong here?
Using
ASSET_URL="/"

Had the effect of generating incorrect URLs like:
//build/assets/app-b30c7c50.css

setting it to
ASSET_URL=""

or
ASSET_URL=null

had no effect at all (meaning still absolute URL was generated).

in your vite.config.js you can specify a base field (which defaults to /), and set it to e.g. ./ to produce relative links to assets in your index.html. ref
